# Why don't my partitions stay mounted after a reboot?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 in a wubi instalation.

As I'm using clementine to listen to music I have in my partitions, each time I power ubuntu up clementine loses the libraries and has to rescan the partition all over again.

A similar thing happens to Transmission bitTorrent client... each time i shutdown the computer and power it up again it loses the location of the files if they are in one of the partitions....

Is there a way to fix this problem? Is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all I must say that I'm a Linux noob that I had the same problem some time ago.

I think that your problem is related with the fact of Ubuntu don't automaticaly mount partitions other than the one with the system itself. Try to make a search in Google by "edit fstab" and take a look on that.

I solved my problem adding the following lines in fstab file:

```
#Windows7 auto-mounted partition
/dev/sda2   /mnt/Windows7   auto   rw,auto,user,exec,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,uid=1000   0   0
```

Comment: based on your exampled i made /dev/sda3 /mnt/windows7 auto rw,auto,user,exec,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,uid=1000 0 0
but i only can see the partition if i run nautilus in sudo mode....

Comment: ended up with /dev/sda3 /media/COMMON auto defaults 0 0 seems to be doing all that i need :)
ty for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

A little trick.

Clementine will mount the partition when you select a folder on it even set for reboot but there is something wrong with the way it does it.

What I do is first get it mounted thru the disks app, make sure mount at startup and life is good.